# How to install dotnet core 2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2

I followed the instructions found on https://www.databinding.net/2017/09/09/net-core-2-0-auf-dem-raspberry-pi/ 
sorry it's in german but the install part is:

```
curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Runtime/release/2.0.0/dotnet-runtime-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && sudo tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
sudo ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
```

I use a Raspberry Pi 2 Version 1.2 and tried the latest official stretch lite

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41+ #1023 Tue Aug 8 15:47:12 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

and jessie lite

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35+ #1014 Fri Jun 30 14:34:49 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

But I had no luck.

```
dotnet --version
```

allways terminates with **segmentation fault**.

Has anyone a running dotnet core 2.0 on a Raspi?
Is it running on stretch or jessie (debian 8 or 9)?

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/setting_up_raspian_and_dotnet_core_2_0_on_a_raspberry_pi/ which has some information about .NET Core 2.0 on Raspbian. And see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560892/is-net-core-ready-to-run-on-raspberry-pi-3 with an answer as well.

Comment: I think this might be an ARMv6/7 issue. Note that your version says `armv6l` rather than ARMv7 or `armhf`, and the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md) say it requires ARMv7 instructions. Perhaps try the full Raspbian if you get chance?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes that's it!
The Raspi I used was an P1 1 B+ and not Pi 2 ;-(

Comment: So? dotnet can't be used on a rpi1?

Answer (score 1):

@Aurora0001 gave the hint!
I failed to validate the Raspi version.
After putting the sd-card into a Raspi 3, the dotnet core 2.0 is running.

```
Linux jessie_lite_pi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

and the dotnet command:

```
$ dotnet --info

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.4-servicing-25824-03
  Build    : 901f257100c6f5e1833c83f9f91beb1f63be1ed2
```